# Session isn't passing over domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In my rails app, when I log in at the www.site.com address, I am logged in just fine. Although without logging out, I go to the site, http://site.com I am logged out, but still logged in at the www.site.com address if I go back.

I can't find anything to set in my environment variables, any idea as to how to keep this session across all domains on my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a session cookie for "site.com", that will be different than "www.site.com." You need to specify the "cookie_domain" as ".site.com" which will set the cookie or all subdomains as well. In PHP, you could use [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) or [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set [session.cookie_domain](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain). In Rails, you can either add a small script to the enviroment.rb - something like:

`ActionController::Base.session_options[:session_domain] = '.site.com'`

(in this case you might also do some switching based on the domain name in production/test/development env's) or try some [other configuration options](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/cookie-handling-in-multi-domain-applications-in-ruby-on-rails/).

Here's more than you'd ever want to know on the [subject](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 5):

Set the session cookie properly; that is, for .site.com and site.com rather than just for www.site.com.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by setting the session cookie properly. I don't ever remember setting it. I just use session[:user_id] and move along.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect www.site.com to site.com (or the other way around). If you don't do that, google may think it's two different sites.

Comment: +1 whilst this doesn't answer the question, it is certainly something you should implement.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 2.3 this has been changed to:

```
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.example.com'
```

or if the session variable hasn't been created yet

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.example.com'}
```

See [Losing session in rails 2.3.2 app using subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663893/losing-session-in-rails-2-3-2-app-using-subdomain/978716)

Answer (score -1):

since they alias www. to .; couldn't you just prepend www. onto the .?