# Losing session in rails 2.3.2 app using subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, restful-authentication

I have a 2.2.3 app which I upgraded to 2.3.2

It's a multi-site (using subdomain) that creates one top level session for all sites.

This is how I change the domain in production.rb:

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:domain] = "example.com"

# in rails 2.2.2, this is what i used to do:
# ActionController::Base.session_options[:session_domain] = "example.com"
```

Strange things started to happen after I upgraded
I can no longer log in using restful authentication; it does authenticate me, but as soon as I'm redirected, it would ask me to log in again.

As I said, I use restful_authentication and I also use passenger 2.1.2.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the Vlad's answer correct ?

Answer (score 7):

Olly's answer is correct, in rails 2.3 it should be:

```
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.example.com'
```

I just wanted to add that if you don't already have some session options created you may receive this when using that:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

In that case you should use this instead (which creates the session variable instead of updating it):

```
config.action_controller.session ||= {}
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.example.com'
```

Edit: apparently Rails 2.2.2 projects use something different. "domain" should be named "session_domain" and take the period character off the front of the domain.  Try this:

```
config.action_controller.session ||= {}
config.action_controller.session[:session_domain] = 'example.com'
```

Comment: This was helpful for me to set secure sessions.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 2.3 you should use

```
config.action_controller.session[:domain] = '.example.com'
```

Comment: I tried putting this in development.rb and got:

undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ahh!  Figured it out.  The session variable hadn't been created yet.
This worked:
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.example.com'}

Answer (score 2):

A more bullet proof solution would be to check if the session already exists or not.  If you are blindly replacing the whole session object it may trip you up in the future.

```
if ActionController::Base.session
  ActionController::Base.session[:domain] = '.example.com'
else
  ActionController::Base.session = { :domain => '.example.com' }
end
```

I like to do this in an initializer file.

Answer (score 1):

You must indicate:

```
.example.com
```

(notice the **leading dot**) in order for the session cookie **to apply to example.com *as well as its sub-domains***.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that another way to handle the whole subdomain thing for the cookies is dynamically. Works in 2.3.4.

Something like this in the environment.rb

```
# solution to use the cookies in the api. domains
# this is relevant but in 2.3.4 the code is different
# http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/cookie-handling-in-multi-domain-applications-in-ruby-on-rails/
# Just making sure that api. shares the domain name
require 'dispatcher'
module ActionController
  class Dispatcher
    def set_session_domain
      host_name = @env['SERVER_NAME']
      new_host_name = whatever #some mod of the host_name, for instance
      ActionController::Base.session = {
        :domain => new_host_name
      }
    end

    before_dispatch :set_session_domain
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Rails 2.3.5 and have

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.localhost:3000'}
```

in my development.rb but I don't get it to work?

Something else you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem (losing sessions, without subdomain), with nginx + thin. Migrating to apache + passenger (last version) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running 2.3.5 and encountering similar issues to @alfred-nerstu

No error messages with the patch from @schickm but it doesn't seem to take, either.

Answer (score 0):

It could be added in the same place where you set the session key and secret

```
config.action_controller.session = {
      :key => '_app_session',
      :domain => '.domain.com',
      :secret => 'secret'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with cookie-based sessions.  Upgrading to Passenger 2.1.3 seemed to fix the issue.